# How do I selected Kendo UI ComboBox value when edit record in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Kendo UI ComboBox in MVC 4 project, I have below scenario.

I am getting stuck when I am in edit mode of record, my URL is "localhost://ControllerName/MethodName/id. I want to select the kendo ui combobox value based on that "id", but I am not able to select the combobox value and my id is GUID type.

Please help for select the combbox value.

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery find

```
$('#IdOfCombo').find(id).text();
```